# Python | Selenium scroll to value 2month timestamp in dynamically loading webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape posts that are not older than 2 months. For this I need to scroll in dynamically loading webpage to reach when posts contain information 2 months, after this, I need to stop scrolling.

I have tried several different options, but it is still not working.

How timestamp looks in the source:

[image: How timestamp looks in the source]

```
scroll = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/section[1]/div/section[4]/div/ul/li[51]/article/div[1]/div/span/time/text() == 2mo'))
```

When webdriver opens the page, I see there is no scroll-down action. It just opens a page.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.